# Сложные заголовки в DataGridView

Tags: c#

Приветствую всех. Возникла потребность сделать сложные заголовки типа

```
|-----------Заголовок1--------|-----------Заголовок2--------|
|подзаголовок1|подзаголовок2|подзаг оловок 3|подзаголовок4|
```

Есть ли сторонние хорошие гриды? Пробовал SourceGrid, но так и не понял, как сделать с ним сложные заголовки.